# Response to ( let’s make it happen sometime.)

Tags: meaning

A friend sent a message

> My friend: Love to have coffee someday
>
> Me: yeah! That would be great
>
> My friend: let’s make it happen sometime.

Does it mean I have to pick a day?

Answer (score 1):

It means they suggest that they would like to do it too, and suggest that it should  be put into action. However, who should initiate the meeting, when or where is not indicated. If you wish to suggest a time and place, that is your prerogative.